# How can I access the entire query string in an ASP.net controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, query-string

I know that if I have an url like XController/Action?id=1, and an action method

```
void Action(int id)
```

the id parameter will automatically be read from the query string.

But how can I access the entire query string when I don't in advance know the name of all parameters. E.g:

```
void Action(QueryStringCollection coll) {
    object id = coll["id"];
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Use-querystring-variables-in-Asp-Net-MVC-controller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use **Request.QueryString** for this

**Request.QueryString.Keys** gives you the name of all parameters

Comment: The only draw back to using Request is you lose the ability to do unit testing on your controller actions without building up a HttpContext. It's just one of those things were another method doesn't exist and the pros usualy outweigh the cons.